# Error while trying to generate JSON Array from MySQL Database in PHP

Tags: php, mysqli, xampp, web-development-server

Here is my PHP code for get_categories.php:

```
<?PHP
    require_once('connection.php');
    $query="SELECT * FROM categories";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection,$query); 
    $return_arr = array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, mysqli_fetch_assoc) 
           {
        $row_array['category'] = $row['category'];
        $row_array['icon'] = $row['icon'];

        array_push($return_arr,$row_array);

    }

    echo json_encode($return_arr);

    ?>
```

and connection.php

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost"; //replace it with your database server name
$username = "root";  //replace it with your database username
$password = "password";  //replace it with your database password
$dbname = "db_client";
// Create connection
$connection = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$connection) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
?>
```

When i run the get_categories.php to generate a json array.. this error appears

**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\get_categories.php on line 7**

Can someone correct me on what i am doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: You're missing a closing `)` on your `while` line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, mysqli_fetch_assoc)`
should be  :
`while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, mysqli_fetch_assoc))`

You're missing a parenthesis

Comment: Questions that are about basic PHP syntax errors should not be answered. They should be closed as a duplicate of [PHP Parse/Syntax Errors; and How to solve them?](//stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071) only.  See: [Should one advise on off topic questions?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276572/1768232). Off-topic questions can be closed and deleted, which could nullify your contribution anyway.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind in the future